# Printing a grid

Tags: c++

I want to print a game board grid which will vary in size depending on what the user inputs. I also wanted to know would it be best or even be possible to make this same grid using an array or would I need some type of 2d array of some sort?

```
void printGrid(int &userRows, int &userColumns){
  cout << "Enter the number of rows -> ";
  cin >> userRows;
  cout << "Enter the number of columns -> ";
  cin >> userColumns;

  for(int i = 0; i < userColumns; i++){
    cout << "|";

    for(int y = 0; y < userRows; y++){
      cout << "-";
    }
  }
}
```

I got the nested loop part down pat. Just having an issue telling it to print a new line and to spawn one after the other. Thank you
[Here is the final product I am going for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ormAe.png)

Comment: The newline should happen after the `userRows` loop, still inside the `userColumns` loop.

Comment: What do you need to put on the board? Is it going to be for like checkers or something? Can it be represented in a fixed width i.e. a single `char`?

Comment: `cout << "-"; } cout << "\n";` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is fairly easy, just understand the pattern! Here's the working code with live example.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void printGrid(int &userRows, int &userColumns){
  cout<<endl;
  cout<<" ";
  int i=1,j;
  for(j = 0; j <= 4*userColumns; j++){
    if(j%4==2)
        cout<<i++;
    else cout<<" ";
  }
  cout<<endl;
  for(i = 0; i <= 2*userRows; i++){
    if(i%2!=0)
      cout<<(char)(i/2 +'A');
    for(j = 0; j <= 2*userColumns; j++){
      if(i%2==0)
      {
        if(j==0)
            cout<<" ";
        if(j%2==0)
            cout<<" ";
        else cout<<"---";
      }
      else{
        if(j%2==0)
            cout<<"|";
        else cout<<"   ";
      }
    }
    if(i%2!=0)
      cout<<(char)(i/2 +'A');
    cout<<endl;
  }
  cout<<" ";
  for(j = 0, i = 1; j <= 4*userColumns; j++){
    if(j%4==2)
        cout<<i++;
    else cout<<" ";
  }
  cout<<endl;
}

int main() {
  int userRows, userColumns;
  cout << "Enter the number of rows -> ";   
  cin >> userRows;   
  cout << "Enter the number of columns -> ";
  cin >> userColumns; 
  printGrid(userRows, userColumns);
  return 0;
}
```

[**Live Code**](https://ideone.com/x3OKAD)

```
Output:

Enter the number of rows -> 4
Enter the number of columns -> 6
   1   2   3   4   5   6  
  --- --- --- --- --- --- 
A|   |   |   |   |   |   |A
  --- --- --- --- --- --- 
B|   |   |   |   |   |   |B
  --- --- --- --- --- --- 
C|   |   |   |   |   |   |C
  --- --- --- --- --- --- 
D|   |   |   |   |   |   |D
  --- --- --- --- --- --- 
   1   2   3   4   5   6
```

Comment: Thank you! I wanted to know how to implement a 2d array in it? I have come up with logic for it I am having an issue with printing it uniformly.

Answer (score 2):

> **I got the nested loop part down pat. Just having an issue telling it to print a new line and to spawn one after the other.**

Are you sure? That doesn't seem to produce anything close to the **final product I am going for**?

While that may produce `"|"` and `"-"` output, it ignores the column headings, the header separator, the row labels, the footer separator and the column footer.

In answer to the `newline` part of your question, you have two options, you can either output a newline with the macro `endl` or you can output a literal newline `"\n"`. If you have declared `using namespace std;`, you can simply use the `cout << endl;` or `cout << "\n";`. otherwise you need to explicitly specify the `std` namespace, e.g. `std::cout << endl;` or `std::cout << "\n";`

To finish building your output with column heading, separators, row labels, footer separator and footer, just take it piece-by-piece. For example for your column headings, you could simply loop over your columns, outputting your `loop counter + 1` with appropriate spacings:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)      /* output column headings */
        if (!i)
            std::cout <<"    " << i+1;
        else
            std::cout <<"   " << i+1;
    std::cout << "\n";
```

(**note:** the use of the `if (!i)` (equivalent to `if (i == 0)`) to handle the first-column spacing separately)

For your heading separator, you could loop over the columns again, in like manner with the same check handling the first column differently.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)      /* output header separators */
        if (!i)
            std::cout <<"   ---";
        else
            std::cout <<" ---";
    std::cout << "\n";
```

Then the actual grid sections requires *row-labels* both before, and after, each row of the grid is output. Here you simply add a nested loop to loop over each row, but otherwise use a similar loop over each column with first row check, followed by a final output of the closing row-label for each row:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {    /* output labeled grid rows */
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            if (!j)
                std::cout << (char)('A' + i) << " |   |";
            else
                std::cout << "   |";
        std::cout << " " << (char)('A' + i) << "\n";
    }
```

Finally, you just repeat what you did for the column headers and header separator in reverse order for your footer separator and footer, outputting the separator row first followed by the column footers, e.g.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)      /* output footer separators */
        if (!i)
            std::cout <<"   ---";
        else
            std::cout <<" ---";
    std::cout << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)      /* output column footer */
        if (!i)
            std::cout <<"    " << i+1;
        else
            std::cout <<"   " << i+1;
    std::cout << "\n";                  /* tidy up with new line */
```

That's pretty much it. You can throw together a short example using a `class board` to hold the `rows` and `cols` values and a constructor and a couple of member functions to update or request input for new row/column values, e.g.  the following just outputs your `4x6` grid, then prompts for new `rows` and `cols` values, and finally output a `5x7` example:

```
#include <iostream>

class board {
    int rows, cols;
  public:
    board() {};
    board (int x, int y) { rows = x; cols = y; }
    void prngrid ();
    void setsize (int x, int y) { rows = x; cols = y; }
    void setsize ();
};

void board::prngrid ()
{
    std::cout << "\n";                  /* output new line before grid */
    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)      /* output column headings */
        if (!i)
            std::cout <<"    " << i+1;
        else
            std::cout <<"   " << i+1;
    std::cout << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)      /* output header separators */
        if (!i)
            std::cout <<"   ---";
        else
            std::cout <<" ---";
    std::cout << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {    /* output labeled grid rows */
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            if (!j)
                std::cout << (char)('A' + i) << " |   |";
            else
                std::cout << "   |";
        std::cout << " " << (char)('A' + i) << "\n";
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)      /* output footer separators */
        if (!i)
            std::cout <<"   ---";
        else
            std::cout <<" ---";
    std::cout << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)      /* output column footer */
        if (!i)
            std::cout <<"    " << i+1;
        else
            std::cout <<"   " << i+1;
    std::cout << "\n";                  /* tidy up with new line */
}

void board::setsize ()
{
    std::cout << "\nenter the number of rows -> ";
    std::cin >> rows;
    std::cout << "enter the number of cols -> ";
    std::cin >> cols;
}

int main (void) {

    board board1 (4, 6);
    board1.prngrid();

    board1.setsize();
    board1.prngrid();

    board1.setsize (5,7);
    board1.prngrid();

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** you should add validation checks that `rows` and `cols` values are non-negative (or choose an `unsigned` type), and also check that they are reasonable for your screen output (e.g. less than `20` or so and at least `26` or less or you will run out of upper-case letters). Those checks, and adjustments for multi-digit headings, are left to you)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/board_grid

    1   2   3   4   5   6
   --- --- --- --- --- ---
A |   |   |   |   |   |   | A
B |   |   |   |   |   |   | B
C |   |   |   |   |   |   | C
D |   |   |   |   |   |   | D
   --- --- --- --- --- ---
    1   2   3   4   5   6

enter the number of rows -> 5
enter the number of cols -> 5

    1   2   3   4   5
   --- --- --- --- ---
A |   |   |   |   |   | A
B |   |   |   |   |   | B
C |   |   |   |   |   | C
D |   |   |   |   |   | D
E |   |   |   |   |   | E
   --- --- --- --- ---
    1   2   3   4   5

    1   2   3   4   5   6   7
   --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
A |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | A
B |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | B
C |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | C
D |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | D
E |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | E
   --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
    1   2   3   4   5   6   7
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 1):

By adding the `cout << endl;` after the **userRows** for-loop has finish the process it will proceed with the next line until `i < userColumns`

```
for(int i = 0; i < userColumns; i++){
    cout << "|";

    for(int y = 0; y < userRows; y++){
      cout << "-";
    }
    cout << endl;  //end of every-line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say:

> make this same grid using an array

I'm guessing you are asking how to handle values you can use to populate the grid. There are lots of ways to store a variable number of values. Here are a few (I'm assuming the values are of type `char`):

1. One dimensional `std::vector`

   ```
   std::vector<char> gridValues;
   gridValues.resize(userColumns * userRows);
   ```

   Then, inside the for loops:

   ```
   cout << gridValues.at( i + y*userColumns );
   ```
2. Two dimensional `std::vector`

   ```
   std::vector<std::vector<char>> gridValues;
   gridValues.resize(userRows);
   for( int i = 0; i < userRows; ++i )
       gridValues.at(i).resize(userColumns);
   ```

   Then, inside the for loops:

   ```
   cout << gridValues.at( y ).at( i );
   ```
3. One dimensional array

   ```
   char* gridValues = new char[ userColumns*userRows ];
   ```

   Then, inside the for loops:

   ```
   cout << gridValues[ i + y*userColumns ];
   ```
4. Two dimensional array

   ```
   char** gridValues = new char[ userRows ];
   for( int i = 0; i < userRows; ++i )
       gridValues[i] = new char[ userColumns ];
   ```

   Then, inside the for loops:

   ```
   cout << gridValues[ y ][ i ];
   ```

I would use the one-dimensional `std::vector`, because it's simple to setup and I don't have to worry about forgetting to delete the pointers at the end.

---

As a note, you may want to check you `for` loops. With `userColumns = 3` and `userRows = 2`, the code you gave will print: `|--|--|--`. The variables are being used backwards.

Once you fix the order of the loops, JaxLee's answer will help you put the newline in the right spot.